# Windows calculator for programmers

Tags: windows, calculator

Currently, I use the standard Windows 7 calculator in "Programmer" mode, and it's great. It does everything I need... except it has no support for unsigned integers. Which is all well and good if you are dealing with 8, 16, or 32 bit integers; just leave it in quad word mode and you won't have any two's compliment problems, but there is no way to represent an unsigned 64 bit integer.

To be clear, I am looking for a windows program, not a chrome extension or simply "use google". The software must support bitwise operators and handle unsigned/signed integers of at least 64 bits in size, and at least hexadecimal, binary, and decimal display. Support for floating point numbers is not necessary, but would be awesome.

Comment: Like [BinCalc](https://sites.google.com/site/bincalc/) but supporting 64 bits...

Comment: Like [Penjee Calc](http://calc.penjee.com/?s=PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP) but offline...

Comment: This is an old question, but still a valid request.  Anyone out there come across a good Programmers Calculator that can handle 128 bit (or larger) integers, signed or otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) (Paid,Cross-Platform)

[SpeedCrunch](http://speedcrunch.org/) (Free, Cross-Platform)

Both of these are great. Exactly what you are looking for.
Hope this resolves your issue!!! cheers!!

Comment: Can you explain how WolframAlpha supports unsigned integers?

Comment: In WA you can import any file with a sequence of 64-bit unsigned integers and can also export a list of integers  in the range (0, 2^64-1) to a binary file.

Comment: What I mean: giving an example would be nice, e.g. it can convert hex to decimal http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0xffffffffffffffff&dataset= but how can I show it interpreted as signed int64?

Comment: Similar for speedcrunch, how would we show sint64. Also, it seems it is not limited to int64, so it would not report an overflow.

Comment: Awesome, it looks like SpeedCrunch is essentially what I was looking for. It'll get the job done perfectly! +1

Comment: The SpeedCrunch people need to fire their web designer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: definitely.  It took me a while to get to the repo page (https://bitbucket.org/heldercorreia/speedcrunch.git), where I could get the source to build it on Linux.  Speedcrunch seems to be what I was looking for: something that works like `bc -l` or `calc`, but with better support for developing bithacks in fixed-size integers, not arbitrary-precision.  It unfortunately opens it's own terminal-like window, instead of just running in an existing terminal, though.

Comment: Actually, speedcrunch uses 256bit integers internally, so bithacks don't always work as expected if truncation to 32 or 64 bits was essential.  You'd have to code that manually. :/

Comment: SpeedCrunch is exactly what I needed. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @PeterCordes both [perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Int64) and powershell are available on Linux, support unsigned 64-bit int and can run in the current terminal in interactive mode

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell can solve all of your problems. Not only does it has a [*64-bit unsigned type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64?view=net-7.0) (and [128-bit signed/unsigned types](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67151) since PowerShell Core 7.0) but it also has an **arbitrary-precision** integer type. Some math examples:

- Arbitrary integer and floating-point math

  ```
  1.56 + 0.23/[math]::Pow([math]::Sqrt([math]::Log(20) + [math]::Sin([math]::PI/3)), 4)
  ```
- Math on decimal type (128-bit): `1.23d * 3.45d / 28`
- Bitwise operations

  ```
  [uint64]::MaxValue/3 + (-bnot 20) + (1L -shl 22) + (0x23 -band 0x34)
  ```
- Big integer math: `[bigint]::Pow([uint64]::MaxValue, 20)`
- 128-bit [signed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0)/[unsigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128?view=net-7.0) math (new since .NET Core 7.0 Preview 5)

[image: PowerShell sample]

PowerShell is like a front-end to the .NET framework, so any .NET or Win32 functions (or even Linux functions in *.so files) can be called from PowerShell. The math functions above are mainly from the [.NET Math class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netcore-3.1) and [Numerics namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=netcore-3.1). Here are some other things that may be useful to programmers:

- Calculate file or object sizes: Use [number suffixes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7) `12.5GB + 5.8MB + 1392KB` for binary units and `12.5e9 + 5.8e6 + 1392e3` for decimal units (G = 1e9, M = 1e6, K = 1e3)
- Convert to/from base64: [`[Convert]::ToBase64String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8) and [`[Convert]::FromBase64String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.8)
- Date/time manipulation. For example convert from raw Epoch values to datetime and vice versa

  ```
    [datetime]::FromFileTime(0x01d15614cbaee92c)
    [datetime]::ParseExact("08-12-2012","dd-MM-yyyy", `
            [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
  ```
- String formatting and base conversion. Anything that [`String.Format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1) in .NET supports will work. For more information read about the [formatting operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f). You can also do advanced string and regex manipulation. Some examples:

  ```
    'somestring'.Substring(4) * 3 -replace 'ings', 'eet'
    '{0:X}' -f (0x12 + 34)
    [convert]::ToString(0x12 + 34, 16)
    'This is an emoji' + [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F60A)
  ```
- Direct XML and JSON manipulation
- Call functions in DLL files directly
- GUI programming. Yes PowerShell is powerful enough for that and many people do write WinForm apps in PowerShell. Here's a small sample [clipboard history app](https://superuser.com/a/1440152/241386)

[image: Clipboard history app in PowerShell]

For more information you can read

- [Doing Math with `System.Math`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-static-classes-and-methods?view=powershell-7#doing-math-with-systemmath)
- [Using Windows PowerShell to Work with Numbers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-windows-powershell-to-work-with-numbers/)
- [Playing with JSON and PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/playing-with-json-and-powershell/)
- [Time conversions in PowerShell (and .NET in general)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sergey_babkins_blog/time-conversions-in-powershell-and-net-in-general)
- [Understanding Numbers in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-numbers-in-powershell/)

or follow [Dr Scripto's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/author/the-scripting-guys/)